# How do I Change Plot with own Y-Range on Demand?

Tags: core-plot, scatter-plot

**Scenario:** 

1) Three plots: One 'datum' plot (default) and three comparison plots; each with their own Y Ranges.

The user could choose either:

2a) One stand-alone'datum' plot (default) or...

2b) A combo of {datum & 1 comparison plot}: 2 plots sharing a combined range (max/min Y of both).

All three plots are initially created/graph.
They are to be toggled to displayed per their ranges on demand.

**Problem:** Changing the graph's Y-Range appears to have an unfavorable (or no) effect: sometimes using the wrong Y-Range (e.g., the combo comparison plots is still using the default datum y-range).

**Question:** What is the best way to change the graph's Y-Range per demand to accommodate the plot scenarios?

**Note:** I've been toggling the plots via add/remove plot from graph.  Essentially, I just re-assign the new Y-Range/graph when I add the new plot(s).

Comment: Do all plots share the same plot space or is there more than one?

Answer (score 0):

The plot(s) should change to reflect the new `xRange` or `yRange` whenever you change them. If you're modifying the existing range, remember that plot ranges are immutable. You need to make a mutable copy of the existing range before modifying it and assigning the new range to the plot space.